# In Jenkins can I use a parameter value in other config fields?

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up a parameterized build on my Jenkins server.

Basically I want to have the *git branch name* as a parameter. Then I want to use that parameter in various other fields in the job config.

I don't know if this is even possible, but I hope that it might be as it seems an obvious need.

The only docs I could find is this old wiki page
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

It shows that build parameter is available as an ENV var, but it doesn't show how to use it elsewhere in the job config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

despite being undocumented, this syntax works in job config fields

```
${PARAM_NAME}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use $PARAM_NAME anywhere in the configure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the "Git parameter" parameter type in your config and then you can reference that simply in the Source Code Management section - see [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/). This assumes that the **Jenkins instance has the Git parameter plugin installed**.

If you don't have that option, then:
you can simply add a String parameter to the configuration and use that in you configuration, but you need to uncheck "Lightweight checkout" to avoid errors like this:

```
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${BRANCH}
```

String parameter declaration:
[image: string parameter declaration]
String parameter usage:
[image: string parameter usage]
[Source of pictures](https://tomd.xyz/jenkins-dynamic-git-branch/)