# How to pass parameter in rtc plugin Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rational-team-concert

I am using RTC plugin for get source from IBM Rational *Teamconcert* in Jenkins, but how can I pass the parameter that I declared using **This project is parameterized** plugin like the image below

[image]

[image]

I used `%variable_name%` but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of a String parameter used in the [Job Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin#TeamConcertPlugin-JobConfiguration) section of this plugin.

However, make sure your Jenkins is running on Windows if you want to use `%A_VARIABLE%` syntax.
If it runs on Linux, that would be `${A_VARIABLE}`.

Comment: My Jenkins is running on Windows. I also tried ${A_VARIABLE}, but not successful. Error detail is:  A project area with name "%PARAM_PROJECTNAME_TEAMCONCERT%" cannot be found.

Comment: @taibc Strange, considering https://stackoverflow.com/a/33279636/6309. Do you see that error during the configuration of the plugin? Or at runtime, when trying to enter a value for that parameter?

Comment: I got this error at runtime. I can use %variable% at another places, like properties fields user.admin=%PARAM_WAS_USERADMIN%
pass.admin=%PARAM_WAS_PASSADMIN%

Comment: @taibc Then it seems to be a bug in https://github.com/jenkinsci/teamconcert-plugin source code, where the project name does not seem to be properly fetched (meaning does not take into account the case where it is an environment variable)

Comment: Thanks @VonC, what should I do ? I want to pass all parameters at "click build" step

Comment: @taibc First test that, if you set an actual project name in that field (not a variable), it does work.

Comment: Yes, it is successful with actual value

Comment: @taibc if that is working, can you check the environment variables of the completed job? Do you see that project name associated to an environment variable (set by the plugin this time, not set by your parameters)

Comment: I can use my variable at window execute batch windows: Eg. echo "Project name" + %PARAM_PROJECTNAME_TEAMCONCERT% . And I think the project name is not associated to an environment variable because I need to specify it to download source from SCM

Comment: "And I think the project name is not associated to an environment variable": exactly, hence my suggestion to report that as a bug to the plugin project.